# How to scan Wi-fi networks continuously until find specific one?

Tags: android, android-wifi, broadcast, receiver, ssid

I just started an app that must connect automatically to an open access point called "DEVICE AP".

I'm already getting a list with wifi networks, but I don't get "DEVICE AP" until I try the scan for three times (more or less).

So, my questions is: How can I scan continuously until I find "DEVICE AP"?

And other one, is it correct to connect to my open network by this way:

```
 private void connectDeviceAccessPoint() {
    String networkSSID = "DEVICE AP";

    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";

    wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();

            //Start service to send messages to device.
            startService(new Intent(WifiActivity.this, SocketService.class));
            doBindService();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly related to your question... but have you considered the security implications of this?

Comment: Sure, actually this step is just for first time configuration, in this connection the app must send the SSID and password of your home network in order to turn device into another element of network

Comment: You might also consider WPS.